# The height of div main (bootstrap) doesn't cover the content inside of it in before collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap v3.0.0 for designing a web page. and noticed that it's difficult for me to put in another div container after my `main` div. As of now, I have a `header` div. When the screen size is smaller, `header` will push `main` further down, so they never collide. This is what I want for my page.

But when trying to make a `footer` container after `main`, the `footer` collides with my `main`, so the `footer` is occupying space over `main`. This occurs when the screen size is large enough to allow my content to lay side-by-side.

When the screen is smaller, the `footer` goes straight to the bottom of the page like it should be, and doesn't collide with 'main'.

---

My HTML goes like:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content" class="col-md-6">
        <div id="content" class="col-md-6">
           content... </div>
        <div id="content" class="col-md-6">
           content...  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Main question**: How can I fix the `main` element, so that I can put a `footer` properly underneath with no collision between 'main' and 'footer'?

Comment: Add your code for your footer. Is it `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`? What do you specify its height and width to be? None of the code you supplied is relevant to the problem you describe. Use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to paste your code and replicate your problem. Then update your answer with the JSFiddle link so we can see what's going on and give you an answer.

Comment: I put the code for my footer above, but it's also not relevant. I didn't put anything like you said in it. This is all the code I have, so it must be relevant.

Comment: Specify a `min-height` attribute on the main content. It doesn't sound like your footer is overlapping the main element,  just that the main element height is getting smaller.

Comment: chRyNan, yes that is probably more accurate to say. I had tried using 'min-height' but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply insert breaks in space between header-main-footer `<br>` or use sticky footer from this template [sticky footer navbar template bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)

Comment: I can't insert '<br>' because as stated above, I never will know the height of '<main>', it will always change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I originally had the following:

```
<div id="main">
         content....
</div></div>
```

But when I added in the following two classes, the `main` element stopped shrinking on a larger screen, and the footer works perfectly now.

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         content....
</div></div></div>
```